# importing csv file into mysql server but only 1st row is inserting and with wrong entries

Tags: mysql

Goal: I have to import CSV file into MySQL server
Problem: Only 1st row is inserting and that too with wrong entry.

formant of my csv file is:

```
lifelock,LifeLock,,web,Tempe,AZ,1-May-07,6850000,USD,b
lifelock,LifeLock,,web,Tempe,AZ,1-Oct-06,6000000,USD,a
lifelock,LifeLock,,web,Tempe,AZ,1-Jan-08,25000000,USD,c
mycityfaces,MyCityFaces,7,web,Scottsdale,AZ,1-Jan-08,50000,USD,seed
flypaper,Flypaper,,web,Phoenix,AZ,1-Feb-08,3000000,USD,a
```

query to create sql table:

```
create table fund(permalink varchar(20), company varchar(20), numEmps int, category varchar(15),
city varchar(20),state varchar(15),fundedDate Date,raisedAmt int, raisedCurrency longtext,round longtext);
```

query to import csv file:

```
load data infile '/var/lib/mysql-files/TechCrunchcontinentalUSA.csv' into table fund fields terminated by ',' 
lines terminated by '\n' (permalink, company, @numEmps , category , city ,state, @funded, @raised, raisedCurrency ,round )
set numEmps=cast(@emps as unsigned), raisedAmt = cast(@raised as unsigned), fundedDate =STR_TO_DATE(@funded, '%d-%b-%Y') ;
```

Output image
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sql query

```
load data infile '/var/lib/mysql-files/TechCrunchcontinentalUSA.csv' into table fund fields terminated by ',' 
lines terminated by '\r' (permalink, company, @numEmps , category , city ,state, @funded, @raised, raisedCurrency ,round )
set numEmps=cast(@emps as unsigned),fundedDate =STR_TO_DATE(@funded, '%d-%b-%y'), raisedAmt = cast(@raised as unsigned) ;
```

I have changed the line terminator from `\n` to `\r` and changed the `date` from `%d-%b-%y` to `%d-%b-%y` because in date `Y` takes 4 digits as year i.e., `2007` as year and in `y` it takes 2 digit year i.e., `07`.

For date format specifier visit [here](http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/functions/str_to_date).

Answer (score 0):

Is your primary key set to `AUTO_INCREMENT`? Also, check if your csv file has newline separator for each line. Sometimes, csv column data can be too big to fit in to your defined db column say your are defining your city column to hold a value of `varchar(20)` but in csv file you have an instance where city is more than 20 characters.

You can always validate your csv using [this](https://csvlint.io/) online tool (make sure you don't have any sensitive data as it is a third party tool)

Alternatively, try this too if your csv file and table name are same:

```
mysqlimport --lines-terminated-by='\n' --fields-terminated-by=',' --fields-enclosed-by='"' --verbose --local db_name TechCrunchcontinentalUSA.csv
```

Provide username and passwords flags `-uroot -proot` if you have one setup.

Comment: The table does `not` have a `primary key` and the CSV file has a new line separator since data is not in a continuous line. The CSV data shown above are the `first 5` lines of the CSV file.